# How to strip a string after a certain amount of words in python

Tags: python, strip, words

I have a paragraph "Lorem ipsum foo bar foobar stuff etc"
In python, how might I strip this string after a certain amount of words say in this case 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two solutions.

The first uses more memory:

```
s = "Lorem ipsum foo bar foobar stuff etc"
print ' '.join(s.split(" ")[:4])
```

The second may be slower:

```
s = "Lorem ipsum foo bar foobar stuff etc"
start = 0
for i in range(4): # number of words
    start = s.find(" ", start+1)
print s[:start]
```

Comment: Thanks ended up using your first solution

Answer (score 2):

If you only want them separated by spaces then:

```
>>>s = "Lorem ipsum foo bar foobar stuff etc"
>>>o = ' '.join(s.split(' ')[:4])
"Lorem ipsum foo bar"
```

should do the trick.

This is very naive, if you need something fancier then `regex` are the way to go. By something fancier I'm referring to more delimiters than spaces, grammar punctuation, etc.

For example:

```
>>>import re
>>>s = "Lorem ipsum foo bar foobar stuff etc"
>>>l = re.split('[\n \r \s \t]', s)
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'foo', 'bar']
>>>str.join(' ', l)
"Lorem ipsum foo bar"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Downvotes are more constructive if they come accompanied with an observation :) Thanks!

Comment: Do you think your code actually works? Please [run](http://ideone.com/RiFwPW) your code before posting

Answer (score 2):

@PauloBlu's answer would work in most cases, except when your paragraph contains words with uneven whitespaces.
Regex can work wonder in such cases

```
>>> s = "Lorem ipsum\tfoo    bar foobar stuff etc"
>>> ''.join(re.findall("^[^\s]+|\s+[^\s]+", s)[:4])
'Lorem ipsum\tfoo    bar'
```

whereas using `str.split` + `str.join` may not provide you the right result

```
>>> ' '.join(s.split(' ')[:4])
'Lorem ipsum\tfoo  '
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers you could also use this form. It's not so different, but it works:

```
s = "Lorem ipsum foo bar foobar stuff etc"

print ' '.join(s.split(' ', 4)[:-1]) 
# the maxsplit arg of split('4' here) could be set to any number 'n'

"Lorem ipsum foo bar"
```